# What does the value (Array) after the comma after the function mean in Javascript? (() => {}, [])

Tags: javascript, syntax

I imagine this has been asked somewhere before but it's pretty hard to describe what I mean without an example so here we go... I'm not a Javascript pro and I have a piece of code (copied and modified from an example) which has this syntax I want to understand (so that i can remove if unneccessary)

```
/* useEffect() is just a lifecycle method for the application */
React.useEffect(() => {

/* To put in context I am getting data from a database */
    AsyncStorage.getItem(id)
      .then((value) => {
        if (value != null) {
          const masterList = JSON.parse(value);
          setData(masterList);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(error);
      });


  }, []);  /* WTF IS THIS ARRAY DOING HERE!!!???*/
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) :
"If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works."

Basically the idea with the use effect hook is that it can be told what changes to state or props will cause the method to be called again. In the case of [] you are stating it should behave as componentDidMount and only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a JavaScript-specific function signature, but rather a React one. In the case you're referencing, the `[]` is being passed as an argument, specifically the second argument. It provides the React function with some additional information it uses to determine the logic it should run.